# I have two pairs of regular expressions which I would like to test to see if they match the same data

Tags: regex

EDIT: the first regex is used only to validate the input. The second one is then used to tell if we should disregard the first part (using split by `\s`) or not - hence the change to `startsWith`.

I have inherited code that has to check codes that match a specific regex:

```
[A-Za-z0-9 -]+(?:[A-Za-z0-9*])$
```

I changed this to remove the regex group.
Now I would like to test that is the same as the regex above.

```
[A-Za-z0-9 -]+[A-Za-z0-9*]$
```

how would I test this without running all the permutations in the world?

Comment: The two patterns will _match_ the same things, but the first pattern will turn off the final character.

Comment: The first 2 will match the same, the last 2 are different, unless you are only interested in the start and not the rest of the line - if you're only interested in `startsWith` then the last regex is the best.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean by "turn off"? the code only needs to validate the input against the regex.

Comment: @bladefist are you asking if `[A-Za-z0-9 -]+(?:[A-Za-z0-9*])$` will match the same as `[A-Za-z0-9 -]+[A-Za-z0-9*]$`? Also, please remove the "PS" section - it's not relevant to the question and its inclusion doesn't improve or clarify your main question and further actually can't cause catastrophic backtracking as you claim.

Comment: @Bohemian It's actually two questions, that I thought could be combined in a method to compare regex's.
The backtracking claim was for the latter.

Comment: @bladefist `"^NOT\\s+.*"` cannot catastrophically backtrack. As per [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ask only *one* question. Please clarify: Are you asking if `[A-Za-z0-9 -]+(?:[A-Za-z0-9*])$` will match the same as `[A-Za-z0-9 -]+[A-Za-z0-9*]$`?

Comment: What relevance is the first paragraph (everything from the top to "startsWith")? If none, please delete it. If there is some relevance, please explain what it is.